# Check if an object has records using python

Tags: soap-api, python

How can I check if an object has records using Python? I only know the object api name and label. I don't know its field names.

The answer may be a boolean or a list of record ID's.

Comment: What about a record count?

Comment: Are you using `simple_salesforce` or `SalesforcePy` or something else? Have you tried anything?

Comment: I'm using simple_salesforce. I tried the following: pd.DataFrame(sf.query("SELECT name FROM Account")['records']). The problem is that not every object has a field "name". What's the api call for record count? could you show an example line of code?

Answer (score 0):

I was using the wrong google search terms apparently. Using the search term mentioned in the comment of [sfdcfox](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/2984/sfdcfox) I stumbled upon [this post](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000008x1dIAA).

Which led to the following simple lines of code which prints an int with the amount of records:

```
obj_info = sf.query("SELECT COUNT() FROM Account")
print(obj_info['totalSize'])
```